# What is the complexity of this for loop, for (int j = i; j < n; j++)?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

what is the complexity of the second for loop? would it be n-i? from my understanding a the first for loop will go n times, but the index in the second for loop is set to i instead.

```
//where n is the number elements in an array
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
   // Some Constant time task
 }
}
```

Comment: So the inner loop will each time make `n-i` cycles...

Comment: If I recall correctly, this will turn into a [triangular number sequence](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/triangular-numbers.html) so the total number of iterations should be `n(n+1)/2`.

Answer (score 5):

If you try to visualise this as a matrix where lines represents `i` and each columns represents `j` you'll see that this forms a triangle with the sides `n`

Example with `n` being 4

```
0 1 2 3
  1 2 3
    2 3
      3
```

The inner loop has (on average) complexity n/2 which is O(n).
The total complexity is n*(n+1)/2 or O(n^2)

Comment: Formula is `n(n+1)/2`, the current one you've listed will only produce 8 iterations in your example instead of 10.

Comment: Thanks @TimHunter

Answer (score 4):

In all, the inner loop iterates `sum(1..n)` times, which is [`n * (n + 1) / 2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), which is O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Answer (score 0):

The number of steps this takes is a [Triangle Number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593318/factorial-but-with-addition). Here's a bit of code I put together in LINQpad (yeah, sorry about answering in C#, but hopefully this is still readable):

```
void Main()
{
    long k = 0;

    // Whatever you want
    const int n = 13;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            k++;
        }
    }

    k.Dump();

    triangleNumber(n).Dump();

    (((n * n) + n) / 2).Dump();
}

int triangleNumber(int number)
{
    if (number == 0) return 0;
    else return number + triangleNumber(number - 1);
}
```

All 3 print statements (`.Dump()` in LINQpad) produce the same answer (91 for the value of `n` I selected, but again you can choose whatever you want).

As others indicated, this is `O(n^2)`. (You can also see [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021489/big-o-notation-of-n2-2n-2) for more details on that).

Answer (score 0):

We can see that the total iteration of the loop is n*(n+1)/2. I am assuming that you are clear with that from the above explanations.

Now let's find the asymptotic time complexity in an easy logical way.
Big Oh, comes to play when the value of n is a large number, in such cases we need not consider the dividing by 2 ( 2 is a constant)  because (large number / 2) is also a large number.

This leaves us with n*(n+1).

As explained above, since n is a large number, (n+1) can be approximated to (n).
thus leaving us with (n*n).

hence the time complexity O(n^2).